# Set timer with random interval

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have the current code:

```
enemyShipTimer = new Timer(2000);
enemyShipTimer.addEventListener("timer", sendEnemy);
enemyShipTimer.start();
```

How do I change the timer so that instead of triggering `sendEnemy` every 2 seconds, it triggers it at a random time between 1 and 3 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Timer` class possess the `delay` property which indicates the delay between two "timer" events. So, you just have to randomly change the delay (for the next spawn) at the beginning of sendEnemy.

```
function sendEnemy(evt:TimerEvent):void {
  Timer(evt.currentTarget).delay = (1+Math.random()*2)*1000; // change the delay until the next call.

  // continue with the usual sendEnemy code.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Triggering between 1 and 3 seconds, means that each second it has 33% chance to be triggered. So:

```
enemyShipTimer = new Timer( 1000 );
enemyShipTimer.addEventListener("timer", function( e:TimerEvent ):void
{
    if( Math.random() < 0.33 )
    {
        trace( "triggered!" );
    }
});
enemyShipTimer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

public class Test extends MovieClip {
    private var _timer:Timer = null;
    public function Test() : void {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _Init);
    }

    private function _Init(e:Event) : void {
        _RandomTimer();
    }

    private function _RandomCount() : Number {
        var min = 1000;
        var max = 2000;
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
    }

    private function _RandomTimer() : void {
        _timer = new Timer(_RandomCount(), 1);
        _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, _OnTimerCall);
        _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, _OnTimerEnd);
        _timer.start();
    }

    private function _OnTimerCall(e:TimerEvent) : void {
        trace(_timer.delay);
    }

    private function _OnTimerEnd(e:TimerEvent) : void {
        _timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, _OnTimerEnd);
        _RandomTimer();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Math.random` function.
You can choose the maximum value of the random function by multiplying it.
But your random would still go to zero, so you have to add it with a starting number.

```
var randomNumber:Number = Math.random(); // Number between 0 - 1
randomNumber *= 2000; // Number between 0 - 2000
randomNumber += 1000; // Number between 1000 - 3000

enemyShipTimer = new Timer(randomNumber);
enemyShipTimer.addEventListener("timer", sendEnemy);
enemyShipTimer.start();
```

Comment: The issue with this code is that it will still send all enemies at the same interval. Given the function name, I guess he want a different interval between each enemy.